# C++/winRT XAML UserControl - access to it's methods and properties

Tags: c++-winrt

I have a XAML Page that contains a XAML UserControl - PageHeading.xaml.
It has a method : ShowErrorMessage(...)
It's x:Name, in the Page, is "RPNHeading"

From the Page's .cpp file I have tried the following two approaches;

```
#include "PageHeading.h"
 ...
RPNHeading().GetBindingExpression(); // FrameworkElement    
RPNHeading().ShowErrorMessage(L"Hello");
```

Intellisense (but not the compiler) likes the first call but not the second.

In my second approach I tried (compiled but run error: thread violation ) :

```
PageHeading ptr;
ptr.ShowErrorMessage(L"Hello");
```

My question - what is the proper way to make this call?

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared the `ShowErrorMessage` function in the idl file? The first approach needs that.

If you prefer the second one, try the following code:

```
PageHeading* ptr = get_self<PageHeading>(RPNHeading());
ptr->ShowErrorMessage(L"Hello");
```